# Cannot convert value of type '[CustomObject]' to expected argument type '[_]'

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, generics, swift3

This is the class declaration:

```
class VXDropdownFormRow<T: SelectableOption>: DropdownFormRow<T> where T: Equatable {
    override init(title: String?, options: [T], selectedOption: T?, cellSelection: FormCellSelectionClosureType?, valueChanged: ((FormRow) -> Void)?) {
        super.init(title: title, options: options, selectedOption: selectedOption, cellSelection: cellSelection, valueChanged: valueChanged)
        self.cellHeight = 74
    }
}
```

I am calling it from another class:

formRow = VXDropdownFormRow(title: NSLocalizedString("xyz", comment: "").uppercased(), options: durationArray, selectedOption:contractDurationtItem , cellSelection: nil, valueChanged: { (row) in
                self.contract.duration = row.value as? ContractDuration
            })

`durationArray` is:

```
var durationArray : [ListItem]
```

which conforms to the protocol `SelectableOption` like said so in the declaration of the class:

```
open class ListItem: NSManagedObject, SelectableOption {
    func setValues(fromJSON json: JSON, sortOrder: Int) {
        defaultValue = json["default"].stringValue == "true" ?  (true) : (false)
        value = json["value"].stringValue
        text = json["text"].stringValue
        localSortOrder = (sortOrder as NSNumber?)
    }
    public func selectableOptionTitle() -> String {
        return self.text!
    }
    public func selectableOptionSectionTitle() -> String {
        return ""
    }

}
```

but the compiler throws an error while building:

```
Cannot convert value of type '[ListItem]' to expected argument type '[_]'
```

[image: Error]

What should I do to fix this error?

Comment: Did you try `VXDropdownFormRow<ListItem>(title: ...)`?

Comment: Doesn't help. Same error.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the problem by fixing the original declaration in my file which was set to be `VXDropdownFormRow<OldClassName>`. Please check the declaration to make sure everything is proper. This error is misleading and doesn't help you find the issue.